# Stop blocking by DataGrid column Binding Converter that uses Ping?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a list of devices (Raspberry Pi's) that I load into a `DataGrid`. I added a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that binds to the HostName and uses a converter that takes that HostName, pings it, and returns a red or green bitmap. I've set `IsAsync = true` on the column binding so it now loads the grid quickly and then goes down through the list pinging. The issue is that it appears to be blocking because the window is unresponsive/slow. I've even tried to use the converter with Threading. Am I out of luck?

XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Online" Header="Online" IsReadOnly="True" Width="45" >
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding HostName, Converter={StaticResource onlineConverter}, IsAsync=True}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Converter

```
public class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ImageSource redSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/PiConsole;component/Resources/red_light.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    public ImageSource greenSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/PiConsole;component/Resources/green_light.png", UriKind.Absolute));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string host = value.ToString().Trim();
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        bool result = false;
        var pingThread = new Thread(() => result = worker.PingDevice(host));
        pingThread.Start();
        pingThread.Join();

        if (result)
        {
            return greenSource;
        }
        else
        {
            return redSource;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}

public class Worker
{
    public bool PingDevice(string _host)
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = ping.Send(_host, 100);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (PingException p)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(p.InnerException);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: By calling `Thread.Join()` you're freezing calling thread. Why not use tasks or [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)?

Comment: Note that even when you set the Binding to `IsAsync = true`, any Binding Converter is still called in the UI thread. Instead of a converter, your could add another property to your view model, which would be called asynchronously.

Comment: I'm open to either. The property sounds like the best option. How would I implement that?

Comment: Add another property of type ImageSource to your view model. Move the code from the Convert method to the property getter (without the additional Thread). Then bind directly to the new property instead of binding to HostName. If necessary, fire a PropertyChanged event for the new property whenever HostName changes.

Comment: My DataContext is a DataTable populated from SQL. Not sure how I'd accomplish this then.  `public MainWindow() {  InitializeComponent(); PiViewTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet.PiView);  this.DataContext = dataSet.PiView.DefaultView; }`

Comment: @Clemens Can you provide any insight?

Comment: Create a view model class with the DataTable in a property, and an ImageSource property as mentioned.

Comment: Uh huh...  `public class PingStatus    {        public ImageSource DeviceStatus { get; set; }        
    }` So how do I refer to this view model in the XAML? Or only in the converter? If in the XAML, how do I feed it the hostname?